# Storing an XLConnect workbook object as data in an R package results in: Error: NullPointerException (Java)

Tags: r, xlconnect

I'm creating my first R package in order to help colleagues perform a series of relatively involved data processing tasks. I have a lot of R functions that help with the data cleaning an analysis, but I am trying to add some things that streamline the workflow to increase speed and reduce error.

One of the steps that my users currently have to perform is to create a specific series of directories and sub-directories in which different files will be stored later on. Next, I have an Excel workbook template that needs to be inserted into specific folders. Currently, I can create the directories with R code but the users have to copy the Excel template to the correct places manually. I wish to do this automatically with an R function because I've observed that it is easy to make errors if this step is done manually--copying the template into the wrong directory, using the wrong version of the template in the wrong place, etc.

Of note, the Excel workbook template that I am trying to regenerate with an R function is pretty complicated. It contains a small amount of data and then a bunch of formatting and hidden formulae. The workbook template has to stay the way it is for legacy reasons. Due to it's complexity, I'm not sure that I can create the template de novo with R functions that put in the base data, set the formatting, and then set the complex formula rules without introducing errors.

My approach so far has been to use:

`myWB<-XLConnect::loadworkbook("C:/My Docs/Template.xlsx")`

in order to create an XLConnect "workbook" object from a copy of the Excel template that I have stored locally on my machine.

If I use `str()` to examine my newly created workbook object, I see:

```
Formal class 'workbook' [package "XLConnect"] with 2 slots
  ..@ filename: chr "C:/My Docs/Template.xlsx"
  ..@ jobj    :Formal class 'jobjRef' [package "rJava"] with 2 slots
  .. .. ..@ jobj  :<externalptr> 
  .. .. ..@ jclass: chr "com/miraisolutions/xlconnect/integration/r/RWorkbookWrapper"
```

This works great for reproducing copies of the .xlsx template while I am working interactively in the same R session. I can use:

```
XLConnect::saveWorkbook(myWorkbook,file="C:/some new folder/new copy of my template.xlsx")
```

I can then go into "some new folder" and sure enough, "new copy of my template.xlsx" is a fully functional copy of my original template, in the new folder.

The problem is that I want my Excel template workbook to live inside my package as some type of object that R can use to re-create the workbook on the machine of anyone who has installed my package, without them having to obtain a copy of the Excel file, store it somewhere, move it around, etc. I tried, therefore using `devtools::use_data(myWB)`in order to store the myWB object as data in my package's data folder as an .rda file (I have also tried this function with internal set to FALSE in order to store myWB in R/ as sysdata.rda).

I then build my package with `LazyData: TRUE` in the description file. I want to use `XLConnect::saveWorkbook(myWB,"C:/New folder/copy of template.xlsx")` to make a copy of my template in the correct directory for the package to use. The functions in the package can see the myWB object, so I know that it was, in fact, lazily loaded, and when I examine the `str(myWB)` everything appears intact:

```
Formal class 'workbook' [package "XLConnect"] with 2 slots
      ..@ filename: chr "C:/My Docs/Template.xlsx"
      ..@ jobj    :Formal class 'jobjRef' [package "rJava"] with 2 slots
      .. .. ..@ jobj  :<externalptr> 
      .. .. ..@ jclass: chr "com/miraisolutions/xlconnect/integration/r/RWorkbookWrapper"
```

When I run XLConnect::saveWorkbook(myWB,"C:/New folder/copy of template.xlsx")`, however, I get the following error:

```
Error: NullPointerException (Java):
```

I know nothing about Java, but I guess the myWB object created by XLConnect is a java object and I'm losing something (a pointer?) when I save the object as data in my R package.

What do I try next?

Comment: Although it does not contribute to the answer: _"I am pretty new to Stack Overflow and am trying to learn how to ask a good question."_ - IMHO a good question has to be skim'able & to the point. Too much background info is - in most cases - counterproductive, because it scares off readers.

Comment: As you say, workbook objects have a reference to a Java object which you won't be able to capture as easily. Is there any reason why you can't simply include your template Excel file as such in the `inst` folder of your package?

Comment: Thank you for the response, Martin, and sorry for the delay in responding. Your solution seems perfect for my needs. This is my first ever R package (still working my way through Hadley's book) so clearly I have much to learn. Thank you for all of your work on XLConnect!